# Balanced brackets using a stack in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im type a program that see if a equation with brackets are balanced, like same amount of left brackets to right. I need to do it with "(",")","[","]","{","}". this is what I have so far:

```
# [import statements]

from stack_array import Stack
# [constants]


def is_balanced(symbolstring):

    s = Stack()
    balanced = True
    index = 0
    while index < len(symbolstring) and balanced:
        symbol = symbolstring[index]
        if symbol == "(" and "[" and"{" :
            s.push(symbol)
        else:
            if s.is_empty():
                balanced = False
            else:
                s.pop()

        index = index + 1

    if balanced and s.is_empty():
        return (True)
    else:
        return(False)
```

and I need to see if I can get an equation like `print(is_balanced("([5x+(2/4(5))])")` 
to work.

Comment: `if symbol == "(" and "[" and"{"` - that's not going to do what you want. `and` is for boolean logic; use `if symbol in ('(', '[', '{')`.

Comment: @user2357112: or `if symbol in '([{'`

Comment: you also need to check `if s.pop() == symbol`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: No, `s.pop()` has to be the opposite of `symbol`.

Comment: thats what I meant :P `{'(':')','{':'}','[':']'}[symbol]`

Comment: is there a way to do it with numbers and +,-,*,/

Comment: Skip the non-brackets.

Comment: how would that code look?

Answer (score 1):

Use `in` to test if a variable has one of several values.

```
if symbol in ['(', '[', '{']:
```

When you pop an item off the stack, you'll want to check that the open symbol matches the close symbol.

```
if s.is_empty():
    balanced = False
else:
    opener = s.pop()

    if opener == '(' and symbol != ')': balanced = False
    if opener == '[' and symbol != ']': balanced = False
    if opener == '{' and symbol != '}': balanced = False
```

Comment: balanced keeps coming up as an unused verabl